# formtastic semantic form layout question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

In formtastic, when create a semantic form, the layout of the object's attributes are always listed **vertically** (one attribute label & value occupy one row) by default.

How to customize the layout so that part of the attributes could be in **horizental** position. For example, I would like to have "`body`" attribute located on the **right** side of "`title`". How to do that?

```
<% semantic_form_for @post do |form| %>
    <% form.inputs do %>
      <%= form.input :title %>
      <%= form.input :body %>
      <%= form.input :section, :as => :radio %>
      ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS to accomplish this task:

```
<%= form.input :title, :wrapper_html => {:class => "left"} %>
```

Then in your stylesheet:

```
.left
{
  float: left;
  /* etc. */
}
```

This will style the container of the form element (li by default)

Comment: please dont use inline styles. just assign a class/id and style it using an external stylesheet.

Comment: I second that, take the above as an example only. In fact I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I tried, but it does not work, for example, I would like to have 'section' located on the right of 'body', I used <%= form.input :section, :wrapper_html => {:class => "left"} %>, and in css file, I defined .left
{
  float: left;

}

Comment: You need to float body left then, not section.

Answer (score 1):

Formtastic provides lots of HTML `class` and `id` hooks on the wrapper `<li>` and elsewhere so that you can style different *types* of inputs generically (eg `li.string`) or specific inputs differently (eg `li#user_email_input`).

You can, as other answers mentioned, add extra classes to the wrapper with `:wrapper_html => { :class => 'whatever' }` to give yourself new hooks when the options above aren't suitable.

From here, it's purely a style/CSS problem. You probably want to float the `<li>` wrappers against each other with `float:left;` and then clear the floats on the containing `<ol>` with `overflow:auto;` or any other clearing technique of your preference.

Answer (score 0):

You'd simple have to change the CSS. However I suggest you just build up the form elements yourself if you need layout customization for specific attributes.